# External dependencies with rosjava

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all, I am a bit confused with the new gradle build system. In the old version of rosjava, I could define my dependencies on external jars within the Manifest file with something like

```
        <rosjava-pathelement location="/home/eich/workspace/Cylinder_Reasoner/cylinderreasoner.jar" />
```

This was than included into the auto-generated property files. How can I set my dependencies with the new gradle build system? The corresponding jar files of the libs are in the main folder of the package. Any Ideas?

Cheers,
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34141/external-dependencies-with-rosjava/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest going through the Gradle Java tutorial: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html

Dependencies should either be pulled from a remote repository or built and installed to your local repository.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on 2012-05-21**:
Yes. Thank you. Just found it. I can simplye call  the dependencies with "compile files" tag. This includes also jars which are not in a repository.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-01-18**:
Could you please post an example of how you did it Markus? Thanks